# Is there anything I can use to remove gorilla glue from hardwood?

Tags: adhesive

I have a very thin layer and some thicker blotchy spots on some steps and was curious how or what I could use to remove it?

Comment: AFAIK anything that'll remove cured polyurethane based adhesives such as Gorilla glue will also destroy the finish, which is either a different polyurethane based product, or something even less resistant. You may as well sand it off and refinish the area. At least steps have easily defined, limited areas where matching finish isn't difficult.

Comment: Try a chisel. If no luck, it's on to sand and refinish. But it might peel off if you get a chisel under it and there was enough dust/dirt/wax on the steps to keep it from making a good bond.

Answer (score 3):

I would first try a plastic scraping tool to see if you can physically remove it.

This page, under the [FAQ tab from the Gorilla Glue site](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/gorilla-wood-glue/) states:

> Wipe off excess glue immediately with a dry cloth or standard paint thinner. Do not drag glue over material, instead make small swipes to remove wet adhesive. Make sure you avoid skin contact. **Cured glue can be removed with a chisel, scraper or sandpaper.**

I'm not positive if a solvent would work, but before you try a solvent, test it on an inconspicuous spot of your floor to ensure it doesn't damage the wood finish.  Try denatured alcohol, mineral spirits, lacquer thinner, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I checked with the [Gorilla Glue website](http://www.gorillatough.com/index.php?page=superglue-faqs), and the only solvent for this glue is acetone. Be careful using acetone as it will strip many clear furniture finishes.  The website also said that it may be necessary to allow the acetone to soak into the glue for awhile to soften it.  Good luck!

Comment: This only applies to the super glue. [This](http://www.gorillatough.com/index.php?page=gg-faqs) page says "Cured glue can be removed with a chisel, scraper or sandpaper."

Comment: Good pick-up. Thanks for the correction on the web reference.

Comment: You should edit the correction into your answer, as comments are second class citizens on Stack Exchange and can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Gorilla Super Glue on a leather strap and it accidentally flopped onto the top of a MacBook Pro surface (the smooth metallic surface I think is aluminum).
Right away I gently rubbed it with a tissue with nail polish remover on it (acetone).
I clean right up.

Comment: Wet "Gorilla Super Glue" (cyanoanacrylate) is not dried Gorilla Glue (polyurethane.) So this is an answer to some question, just not the one being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I used Solvo-Plast 11 ( made in Canada) an adhesive remover and WoW, it cleaned my mess up really well. I had put the gorilla glue on the inside  of my Moms handles for her walker because they were sliding off, it expanded and came out the opening and dripped all over the place. Worked lickety split and even off my hands, although I didn't really have much on them so can't really say if it would unstick you from something, and I'm not going to test my theory.